# Avoid image caching in browser in React

Tags: reactjs, caching, browser, state, no-cache

I have a code where the user's avatar is fetched from the backend. Now, the avatar file name is the same every time, even if a user uploads a new one because the backend replaces the old avatar with the new one with the same name. Since this was causing caching issue on the browser, I used `[IMAGE_URL]?random={new Date().getSeconds()}` to update the state immediately when user changes it. But this causes the avatar to download multiple times when the page loads or when a React state updates. Is there a way so that the image is not cached and also I don't have to put some `random` query strings?

Comment: You can append the upload timestamp to the image url

Answer (score 2):

you have to implement a hash mechanism on your backend to add a hash string to the image name not on the client side

Comment: I use the updatedAt on the backend for this as extra query-param after the image url